# Shell scripting: How to check if an input argument is a Math operator

Tags: bash, shell

I want to build a basic calculator where i will give as arguments two numbers and one of these +,-,/,* . Example 1+2=3 . I know how to check if an argument is a number but how about the symbols?

Comment: You should probably be using `case` to select the action for each input. If it doesn't match any of the valid ones, you should have a `*` entry at the end that prints an error.

Comment: Which Shell are you using? See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350556/creating-a-calculator-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
case "$op" in
    '*') result=$(($arg1 * $arg2))
        ;;
    /) # code for division
        ;;
    -) # code for subtraction
        ;;
    +) # code for addition
        ;;
    *) echo "Unknown operator '$op'"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks but what should i put as code for each of these?Can you write it with $1 and $3?Thanks

Comment: That's your calculator code. I'm not going to write that for you.

Comment: I added an example for multiplication

Comment: Thank you Barmar appreciate it.