# How to disable special characters in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, special-characters, positional-parameter

I've created a script which performs a calculation. For example:
`count 1 + 3`

`1 + 3 = 4`,
`-` and `/` also works, but if I type
count `1 * 3`, I got

Should be number operand number

Here is a part of a script:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "Should be number operand number"
        exit 1
fi
...
elif [ "$2" = "*" ]; then
        result=`echo $1 \* $3 | bc`
  echo "$1 * $3 = $result"
```

Yes, if I type `\` before `*` in command line it would work, but I need it to run just with a `*`.

I've tried to use set `-f` inside the script it did not work (yes it disables special characters if I type in bash itself but it is not what I need). There is also a `shopt` command that controls shell behavior, so I've tried to enable some options like `shopt -s globstar`, `nullglob`, `promptvars`, etc. It did not work. I put the command before if statement maybe it is wrong.

I would appreciate if someone corrects me or tells the other way to disable interpretation of a special character from inside the script.

Comment: When you run `count 1 * 3`, the `*` is replaced with a list of filenames **before `count` is invoked**. That means that `count` can't possibly do anything to prevent it; the replacement happened before it was loaded, or even identified on-disk.

Comment: Alright, thanks, so I have to rewrite the script in the other way then...

Comment: @Josh My answer includes another way.

Comment: Just use single quotes, some shell function examples:  `f() { echo $(( $1 )) ; }`, then    `f '2 * 32'`, which prints `64`.   Prefer STDIN, do:     `f() { while read x ; do echo $(( $x )) ; done ; }`, use that to print the first ten factorials:     `for x in $(seq 10) ; do seq -s'*' $x | f ; done`.

Answer (score 3):

This exact problem is mentioned in the [POSIX specification of expr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expr.html), saying that the tool has a "rather difficult syntax" for the reason you describe.

This is definitely a known problem, in other words, and POSIX itself leaves it unsolved. You should really consider working with Unix and do the same, rather than trying to work against it.

Some options are:

- Require the entire expression to one quoted argument, e.g. `count "1 * 2"`

  This is a pragmatic, fail-fast way of ensuring that the argument is always quoted, so that any introduction of * still works. The bash builtin `let` does this.
- `read` the expression yourself, e.g. just run `count` and then type in `1 * 2`.

  This avoids the shell touching your data, so that you can interpret it however you want. It's what `bc` and `dc` do.
- Live with the fact that passing `*` will require careful quoting.

  This is what `expr` does.
- Use a [magic alias](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html) hack that only works on certain shells under very specific circumstances.

  This is what no one does, because it's fragile and unpredictable, even though it in some cases allows the syntax you want.

Comment: I'd never seen that magic alias hack before; it's beautifully horrible!

Answer (score 0):

Always quote when you echo. You need to quote the variable reference as well:

```
me$ FOO="BAR * BAR"
me$ echo "$FOO"
BAR * BAR
```

If you don't use double quote, bash will see `*` and perform [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion). `*` expands to all files in your current directory.

However in saying this you would have to be using single quotes for the `*`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$2" = "*" ]; then
    result=`echo $1 \* $3 | bc`
    echo "$1 * $3 = $result"
fi
```

The following would work:

```
» count.sh 2 '*' 1
2 * 2 = 4
```

There is nothing you can do in your program, because the `*` expansion is done by the shell (in contrast to Windows, where it's done by the program).

Here's another [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350556/creating-a-calculator-script) using a menu-driven approach instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    read -p "what's the first number? " n1
    read -p "what's the second number? " n2
    PS3="what's the operation? "
    select ans in add subtract multiply divide; do
        case $ans in 
            add) op='+' ; break ;;
            subtract) op='-' ; break ;;
            multiply) op='*' ; break ;;
            divide) op='/' ; break ;;
            *) echo "invalid response" ;;
        esac
    done
    ans=$(echo "$n1 $op $n2" | bc -l)
    printf "%s %s %s = %s\n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2" "$ans"
done

what's the first number? 5
what's the second number? 4
1) add
2) subtract
3) multiply
4) divide
what's the operation? /
invalid response
what's the operation? 4
5 / 4 = 1.25000000000000000000
```

In short, quote everything where you do not require the shell to perform token splitting and wildcard expansion.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes I know if I write 2 '*' 1 or 2 /* 1 it would work, but I was curious if there is the way to just type 2 * 2 without using escape characters in command line.